# Esconder uma coluna no datatables

Tags: jquery-datatables

Tenho uma tabela em datatables, que tem 5 colunas e uma delas é  tem um id que quero esconder ao utilizador, e é logo na primeira coluna depois na quinta coluna tenho um botao onde tenho o estado mas para mudar o estado de saber o id que já consigo obter da coluna 1 mas quero esconder a coluna e achar o valor na mesma. É possivel?

Comment: Favor postar seu código. Assim fica difícil.

Comment: Se lesse estava em baixo

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de colocar o `visible: false` no columnDefs tenta colocar no columns

```
var table = $('#table-coletores').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    responsive: true,
    lengthMenu: [[10,50,100],[10,50,100]],
    ajax: '{!! route('datatable.coletores') !!}',
    language: { 
        'url' : '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json',
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'tracking_code' },
        { data: 'status_formatted' },
        { data: 'days_left' },
        { data: 'customer_name' },
        { data: 'price_day' },
        { data: 'action', class: 'text-right', visible: false },
    ]
});
```

Como na última coluna,  acabei de testar aqui e funcionou usando a versão  1.10.13

Comment: eu não quero esconder apenas quero meter tipo um id que depois possa ir usar mas o cliente nao pode ver esse id

Comment: estou a usar TableTools 2.2.4 entre outros

Comment: qual é o ficheiro é que são tantos

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei esta documentação no próprio [site do datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html):

Adicione o atributo `"visible": false` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: não funcionou esse já tinha testado

Comment: eu carrego os dados por ajax no datatables , não dá para meter display none

Comment: eu carrego os dados por ajax veja o exemplo acima